# When I serialize an object of a class with a enum property to JSON, if the value is null, the resulting json is borked

Tags: c#, json, enums

When I serialize an object of a class with a enum property to JSON, if the value is null, the resulting json string has a name value pair like this:

```
"controlType":"-2147483648"
```

This causes issues when I deserialize the string to a strongly typed object.

What's the best way of handling enums and nulls?

Comment: Did this question get answered to your liking?

Answer (score 7):

the below code gives you json = '**{"Name":"Test","Id":1,"MyEnum":3}**', when you have a non-null value.

```
public enum SerializeObjTestClassEnum {
  one = 1, two, three, four
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializeObjTestClass {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public SerializeObjTestClassEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public void SerializeObject_Test_Basic_Object() {
  var obj = new SerializeObjTestClass {
    Id = 1, Name = "Test", MyEnum = SerializeObjTestClassEnum.three
  };
  var json = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(obj);
}
```

---

this code gives you json = '**{"Name":"Test","Id":1,"MyEnum":0}**'

`var obj = new SerializeObjTestClass { Id = 1, Name = "Test" };`

Notice how the enum, when not set, is serialized to a 0, while the enum itself starts out at 1.  So this is how you code can know a NULL value was used for the enum.

if you want the json to look like '**{"Name":"Test","Id":1,"MyEnum":null}**', then you're going to need to fake it out by using a class wrapper around the Enum.

Comment: The wrapper `is Nullable<T>`, replace `MyEnum` with `MyEnum?`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
echo json_encode(array("test"=>null));
```

This produces:

```
{"test":null}
```

The best way to handle enums is with a key,value array or an stdClass. Just bind your names to a set of unique integers.  You can then bind the other direction as well:

{"A":1,
"B":2,
"C":3,
1:"A",
2:"B",
3:"C"}

This at least gives you bi-directionality.